# How to fix this error in dim of data.frame

Tags: r, excel, file, dataframe

I need to create a data.frame with 2 matrixs but something is wrong

This is the code:

```
#reading data from excel files
meds<-read.xlsx("medidas.xlsx",1)
ress<-read.xlsx("resultados.xlsx",1)

#creating data.frame with two matrixs
datos<-data.frame(meds=I(meds),ress=I(ress))

datos
```

I obtain an error here
any clue please...thnks!!!

I need the data in this format for further use with other mathematical function

> Error in dim(rvec) <- dim(x) : 
>     dims [producto 474] no coincide con la longitud del objeto [3]

Comment: Translation of the Spanish error message: dims [product %d] do not match the length of object [%d]"

Comment: can you please `dput(meds)` and `res`?

Comment: Thanks Dominique ;)

Comment: Vivek, I got results in this way:

Comment: meds<-read.xlsx("medidas.xlsx",1)
ress<-read.xlsx("resultados.xlsx",1)

mmedds<-matrix(unlist(meds),ncol=3,nrow=158)
mress<-matrix(unlist(ress),ncol=2,nrow=158)

datos<-data.frame(I(mmedds),I(mress))

Comment: Thnks in advance!!!